# Detect when a clientsocket attempts to connect to a serversocket

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

I create a serversocket and bind it to a local port, then tell it to queue a max of 5 connections in the backlog. I want a way to detect when a clientsocket connects to the serversocket/when the backlog has a queued connection. I'm running the socket.accept() in a separate thread and need to be able to stop the separate thread which i can't do when the thread is hanging for on socket.accept().

The reason for this is that I am trying to have the server socket only listen for connections when a user runs a command and then stop when a user runs a different command.

I would like my code to read something like:

```
serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
serversocket.bind((socket.gethostname(), 1024))
serversocket.listen(5)

class connectListner (threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        while True:
            if <item in backlog>:
                clientsocket, address = serversocket.accept()
            pass
```

I can then use thread.join() to stop the thread

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: 'rying to have the server socket only listen for connections when a user runs a command and then stop when a user runs a different command' - OK ignoring the wierdness of this requirement, if you want to stop the listener, set some'ServerClose' bool and then close the serversocket - accept() will then return with an error.

Comment: the idea behind the weirdness is that i'm using the server not as an data distributor but to control the clients and once iv'e started the control i don't want to have additional clients connect as the control commands would be in the wrong order - i know there's more elegant ways of doing this but this would be additional code that could be prevented by preventing the server from listing for connections

Comment: running socket.close() gives me an OSerror which would be fine in a try, except

Comment: try: clientsocket, address = serversocket.accept() except OSerror: break

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose you to use set the socket to non-blocking mode, and to use `select` to
know when a client is waiting for `accept`, since the server socket becomes readable:

```
serversocket.setblocking(False)

readable, writable, err = select.select([serversocket.fileno()], [], [], 1)
if readable:
    clientsocket, address = serversocket.accept()
```

After 1 second, if no client is connected, the select call ends, and will be started
again by your `while` loop. So, you can exit the thread if `readable` is an empty
list, for example. Feel free to set a lower timeout for the `select` if you need
more fined-grain control on the thread.

Comment: as this method allows me stop accepting connections queue connections then accept them again i prefer it - it's more flexible